# Java exception throw

Tags: java, exception

How to throw an exception in Java, tried code below but it raised a compilation error

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        throw new Exception("This is not allowed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about checked exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070932/java-unchecked-checked-exception-clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Exception` and its subclasses (besides `RuntimeException` and its subclasses) cannot be thrown without a try-catch clause, or a `throws Exception` in the method declaration.

You'll need to declare your main as

`public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`

or instead of an `Exception`, throw a `RuntimeException` (or its subclass).

Answer (score 0):

### Exception Handling

The `Exception` represents exceptional event or situation which demands altered program flow.

The keywords `try`, `catch`, `throw`, `throws`, `finally` facilitate the modification of program flow.

The simple idea is that `Exception`s are **thrown** from where they occur or are found, and **caught** where they are intended to be handled. This allows a sudden jump in the program execution, thus achieving modified program flow.

---

### The Balance

There has to be someone who can catch it, otherwise it wouldn't be right to throw it. This is the **cause of your error**. You did not **specify how or where** would the **exception be handled**, and threw it in the air.

---

### Solution

1. **Handle it right there**

   ```
   class Demo{
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           try { // Signifies possibility of exceptional situation
               throw new Exception("This is not allowed"); // Exception is created
                                                           // and thrown
           } catch (Exception ex) { // Here is how it can be handled
               // Do operations on ex (treated as method argument or local variable)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Force someone else to handle it**

   ```
   class Demo{
       public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { // Anyone who calls main
                                                                 // will be forced to do
                                                                 // it in a try-catch
                                                                 // clause or be inside
                                                                 // a method which itself
                                                                 // throws Exception
           throw new Exception("This is not allowed");
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps